# place tags on android imageview objects

Tags: android, tags, imageview, android-view

Is there any way that i can place multiple on a image in android activity

like instagram shows people's names as tag on the images

i have the X and Y position of the tags in pixel format of original image

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout and put your ImageView and TextView inside it so that they will be overlapping